# Combine Boxes and Lines into Single R Chart Legend

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a histogram with two superimposed curve fits in R.  So far, everything is working but the legend.  I want a single legend that includes the boxes for the histogram and the lines for the fitted curves.  I can get it working with the code below, but this creates two separate legends.  Is it possible to combine the legends into a single box?

[image: I want a single legend, not two]

```
truehist(
    data=DismissalRateData$DismissalRate,
    breaks=seq(.6, 1, by=.025),
    col="lightgreen",
    prob=TRUE, 
    ylab="Density",
    xlab="Claim Dismissal Rate", 
    main="Histogram of Historical Claim Dismissal Rates \n(With Superimposed Beta Curve Fits)", 
    xaxt='n',
    yaxt='n',
    ylim=c(0,14)
    )

curve(
    dbeta(x, FittedAlphaParameter, FittedBetaParameter),
    add=TRUE,
    col="red", 
    lwd=3
    )

curve(
    dbeta(x, 100.2753, 11.5809),
    add=TRUE,
    col="blue", 
    lwd=3
    )

axis(
    side=1, 
    at=seq(.6, 1, by=.025),
    labels=formattable::percent(seq(.6, 1, by=.025),digits=0)
    )

legend(x="topleft", legend="Actual Data", fill="lightgreen", col="black")

legend(x="left" ,
    legend=c("Beta fitted with all data 2006-2017", "Beta fitted excluding 2006-2008"),
    col=c("red", "blue"), 
    lty=1, lwd=3)
```